# Почему присвоение переменной l1 = l.reverse() не работает как l1 = l

Tags: python

```
l = [1,2,3]
l1 = l.reverse()
print(l1) >> None
l1 = l
l1     >> [1,2,3]
```

Почему присвоение переменной l1 = l.reverse(l) не работает как l1 = l

Comment: Всё работает: функция `reverse` согласно документации всегда возвращает `None`, и внутри переменной `l1` оказывается этот самый `None`, так и должно быть.

Comment: смотрите l.reverse() изменяет список Inplace и мы этому списку присваиваем еще одну переменную l1 разве не так? По идее, данное действие эквивалентно l1 = l только с одновременным применением функции

Comment: «мы этому списку присваиваем еще одну переменную l1» — в этой фразе написана какая-то чепуха. В показанном коде создаётся переменная `l1`, в которую помещается результат вызова `l.reverse()`, и так как этот результат всегда `None`, то в переменной `l1` тоже будет всегда `None`

Comment: вообще то я думал, что создается всегда объект,  а объекту потом присваивается имя переменной. Как может быть создана переменная до создания объекта?

Comment: Ну да, сперва «создаётся» объект `None` и потом этот объект помещается в переменную `l1`.

Comment: Метод списка `reverse` изменяет сам список, к которому он применяется, но не возвращает его, а возвращает `None`. Есть функция `reversed()`, которая наоборот не меняет исходный список, а возвращает его "перевернутую" копию - возможно вам нужна была эта функция. Операция `l1 = l` только копирует ссылку на один и тот же список в другую переменную (не копирует список), не знаю что вы этим хотели продемонстрировать.